# operator < cannot be applied to java.lang.String,char

Tags: java, encryption

Let me get this out of the way, I am a beginner in java.  I am having trouble with a section of my code.

```
public class Cipher { 

private int secretKey;
private int superSecretKey;

/**
 *
 * @param key the variable used to shift the number of letter
 */
public Cipher(int key) { 
    secretKey = key;
    superSecretKey = key;
}

/**
 *
 * @param s the string to be encrypted
 * @return encrypted string
 */
public String caesarEncrypt (String s) {
    String r = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        char c = (char) (s.charAt(i));
        if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) { 
                r += (char) ('A' + (c - 'A' + secretKey) % 26);
            }
            else {
                r += (char) ('a' + (c - 'a' + secretKey) % 26);
            }
        }
            else {
            r += c;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

/**
 *
 * @param s the string to be decrypted
 * @return the decrypted string
 */
public String caesarDecrypt (String s) {
    String r = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        char c = (char) (s.charAt(i));
        if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                int tmp = (char) ('A' + (c - 'A' - secretKey) % 26);
                if (tmp < 'A') r +=26;
            r += (char) (tmp);
            }
            else {
                int tmp = (char) ('a' + (c - 'a' - secretKey) % 26);
                if (tmp < 'A') r +=26;
            r += (char) (tmp);
            }
        }
            else {
            r += c;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

/**
 *
 * @param s the string to be encrypted using the augustus encryption
 * @return the encrypted string
 */
public String augustusEncrypt (String s) {
      String tmp = caesarEncrypt(s);
      String r = "";
      String newStringKey = Integer.toString(superSecretKey);
      int index = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

         char c = (char) (s.charAt(i));
         if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
             char augKey = newStringKey.charAt(index++ % newStringKey.length());  
             if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                 r += (char)('A' - (c - 'A' + Character.getNumericValue (augKey)) % 26);
             }
             else {
                 r += (char)('a' - (c - 'a' + Character.getNumericValue (augKey)) % 26);
         }      
     }
         else {
         r += c;
     }        
 }
 return r;
}

/**
 *
 * @param s the string to be decrypted using the augustus decryption
 * @return the decrypted string
 */
public String augustusDecrypt (String s) {
     String dec = caesarDecrypt(s);
     String r = "";
     String newStringKey = Integer.toString(superSecretKey);
     int index = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

     char c = (char) (s.charAt(i));
         if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
             char augKey = newStringKey.charAt(index++ % newStringKey.length());  
             if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                 r += (char)('A' - (c - 'A' - Character.getNumericValue (augKey)) % 26);
                 if (dec < 'A') r +=26;
            r += (char) (dec);
             }
             else {
                 r += (char)('a' - (c - 'a' - Character.getNumericValue (augKey)) % 26);
                 if (dec < 'A') r +=26;
            r += (char) (dec);
         }      
     }
         else {
         r += c;
     }        
 }
 return aug;
}



}
```

Above is the entire code because my one part that needs fixing requires other parts. This next piece of code is the method I am having trouble with.

```
public String augustusDecrypt (String s) {
     String dec = caesarDecrypt(s);
     String r = "";
     String newStringKey = Integer.toString(superSecretKey);
     int index = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

     char c = (char) (s.charAt(i));
         if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
             char augKey = newStringKey.charAt(index++ % newStringKey.length());  
             if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                 r += (char)('A' - (c - 'A' - Character.getNumericValue (augKey)) % 26);
                 if (dec < 'A') r +=26;
            r += (char) (dec);
             }
             else {
                 r += (char)('a' - (c - 'a' - Character.getNumericValue (augKey)) % 26);
                 if (dec < 'A') r +=26;
            r += (char) (dec);
         }      
     }
         else {
         r += c;
     }        
 }
 return aug;
}
```

In the for loop, I am getting an operator error.  This line of code exactly.

```
if (dec < 'A') r +=26;
```

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `dec` is a `String` and `<` is not defined for `String`s.

Comment: You are comparing a `String` with a `char`. That doesn't work.

Comment: You probably wanted to write `if (c < 'A')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to determine if a string (dec) is less than a character ('A'), which doesn't make sense. It isn't clear to me what your code is trying to do. Perhaps what you meant to do was:

```
if (dec.charAt(i) < 'A') r +=26;
```

In any case, your first operand needs to be a character type.